# Xamarin Forms Xaml Android Preview error

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

At some point in development the Xaml previewer stopped working for my Xamarin forms app, the app runs fine it just slows down visual testing.

I'm not quite sure how to diagnose the issue as I'm not sure where it's coming from. Image attached so what I'm working with. Cleared the /bin /obj and other caches, installed latest updates.

The full error is,

> System.TypeInitializationException was thrown. The type initializer
>   for 'Kwike.App' threw an exception.
>
> at  at offset 51 in file:line:column :0:0
>
> at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj,
>   System.Object[] parameters) in :0

iOS works fine. It could have something to do with a particular style or resource but I'm not sure. Is there a way to debug more info out of this. Also, this might sound silly but I'm not sure what Kwike.App is that is the name of the app but I cannot locate this file.

It's project specific as the previewer works on a new forms project.

[image]

Comment: Are you use FFImageLoading?

Comment: From what I've seen that's an add-on or plugin right? I don't believe so.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue?  I'm getting this issue using Azure Mobiles Quick Start Client App.

Comment: No I never did, I kinda just eyeball the iOS version then painstakingly adjust the android version to match.